# $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_a^b f(x)g(x) \,dx$, Show that $p_n$ is the monic polynomial of degree $n$ of smallest norm

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

> Let $p_0,p_1,p_2,\cdots$ be monic polynmials orthogonal with respect
>   to $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_a^b f(x)g(x) \,dx$, $p_i$ of degree $i$. Show that
>   $p_n$ is the monic polynomial of degree $n$ of smallest norm ($\lVert p\rVert =
> \langle p,p\rangle^{1/2}$)

I'm studying numerical methods and we're seeing orthogonality of polynomials and projection of things onto subspaces. I need to solve the exercise above using these concepts. I don't know if I understand the exercise correctly. I think I must show that, given a degree $n$, then of all polynomials of this degree, the monic is the one with smallest norm. Am I rigth? I have no idea how to start.

Comment: No; what you have is that the $p_i$ are pairwise orthogonal and of norm $1$, and that $p_k$ is monic of degree $k$. What you want to show is that among *all* monic polynomials of degree $n$, $p_n$ is the one with the smallest norm. HINT: Consider the projection onto the space of polynomails of degree at most $n$.

Comment: Hint: All the polynomials of degree at most $ n $ is a real linear space, and $ \langle f, g\rangle $ gives you an inner product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p_i, i\leq n$ span the space of all polynomials of degree at most $n$. If $q$ is any monic polynomial of degree $n$ then $q-p_n$ is orthogonal to $p_n$ because degree of $q-p_n$  is at most $n-1$ and hence it belongs to the span of $p_i:i<n$. Hence $\|q\|^{2}=\|(q-p_n)+p_n\|^{2}=\|q-p_n\|^{2}+\|p_n\|^{2}$ which implies $\|q\|^{2} \geq \|p_n\|^{2}$.

Comment: what is $p_n$??

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking . Don't you have $p_n$'s given to you?

Comment: Sorry you're rigth, $p_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.

Comment: are you using that $p_i, i\leq n$ is orthogonal to $p_i, i< n$? Why?

Comment: $p_n$ is orthogonal to $p_i, i<n$ and $p_i, i<n$ span the space of all polynomials of degree $\leq n-1$. [ Because this space has dimension $n$ and $p_i, i<n$ are $n$ linearly independent elements in this space. Hence $p_n$ is orthogonal to $q-p_n$.